# How are DataTextField and DataValueFields evaluated

Tags: asp.net, datasource, databound-controls

For a data bound control it is common scenario where we provide `data text field` and `data value field` ( in simple controls like `Dropdownlist`) but **more fields** in controls like `Gridview`.  Generally the datasource is of type `IEnumerable`.

- How does the control internally process these values or rather how do they get the value from the data source without knowing what kind of datasource they are dealing with.
- Can someone explain with code how the controls evaluate these fields from the data source.

Comment: They DataSource is usually of type Object not IEnumerable and they use reflection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Lloyd very thank you for clearing that, but internally they check if it is IEnumerable, IList i  suppose because object cannot be enumerated i suppose

Comment: You can iterate over the properties of an Object, which is how you can bind an Object to items like a DetailsView

Comment: @Lloyd It is still unclear to me, a code snippet perhaps will clear my doubt's about reflection being used to get values.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never knew i could find this information so easily and LLyod was in fact wrong on using reflection to find data from a datasource. None of the data controls use it when i inspected through `Reflector` ;(

link that solved the problem

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366540.aspx

how you do it is below

```
protected override void PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable retrievedData)
        {
            base.PerformDataBinding(retrievedData);

            // Verify data exists.
            if (retrievedData != null)
            {

                string dataStr = String.Empty;

                foreach (object dataItem in retrievedData)
                {
                    if (DataTextField.Length > 0)
                    {
                        dataStr = DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(dataItem,
                            DataTextField, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PropertyDescriptorCollection props =
                                TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(dataItem);
                        if (props.Count >= 1)
                        {
                            if (null != props[0].GetValue(dataItem))
                            {
                                dataStr = props[0].GetValue(dataItem).ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

If the above code seem Greek and Latin , you will have to have a course on asp.net controls development to understand what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Typically, the data-bound control (or concerned components such as
   `DataControlField` in GridView) will handle [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.databinding.aspx) event.
2. Within event handler, the data item that is being currently bound (e.g. `DataRowView` or entity instance) is retrieved. This is done via [DataBinder.GetDataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3ez4ta7.aspx) passing the actual control or control's [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx). For example, if you are implementing a lower level control such as `DataControlField` for higher level data-bound control such as `GridView` then it would handle data-binding of a cell control and hence it will use cell's naming container to pass to `DataBinder.GetDataItem` method which uses current data binding context to get the same.
3. Once the data item object is retrieved, one need to evaluate the given data-binding expression against it to get the actual value and apply any formatting as per different properties set to the control/component. The most simple way is to use [DataBinder.Eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.databinder.eval.aspx) overload. However, one may use the more efficient ways - for example, say `DataField` string is going to be only property name then you may look and cache the property descriptor and then use the same against different data items.

I will suggest you to use tool such as Reflector to inspect relevant control's code to get the better idea.

Comment: Yeah i would also like to know a reason for the downvote , @vinay has answered most of the controls related question here on SO ( every one of my too).

Comment: if i am exposing a DataSource property of repeater inside UserControl in `ascx` file, when should i call the `.DataBind()` method.

Comment: @Deeptechtons, tricky situation - make sense to call `DataBind` as late as possible (say pre-render) but in post-back scenarios, you want data-binding to appear early so that state for dynamically generated controls would load up correctly. Better alternative can be to call data-bind as soon as DataSource property is set by consumer.